# A conjectured vanishing sum involving the Thue–Morse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, conjectures

Let's define $t_n$ by the recurrence
$$t_0 = 1, \quad t_n = (-1)^n \, t_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}.\tag1$$
It is easy to see that $|t_n|=1$, and the signs follow the same pattern as  the [Thue–Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence):
$$1,\,-1,\,-1,\,1,\,-1,\,1,\,1,\,-1,\,-1,\,1,\,1,\,-1,\,1,\,-1,\,-1,\,1,\,...\tag2$$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891648/19661) for an example of a non-recursive formula for $t_n$).

Now, define:
$$\mathcal{S}(m, n)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}t_k\,k^m, \quad \color{gray}{m,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+.}\tag3$$
Computing some values of this sum immediately leads to the following conjecture:

> $$\text{For all }\, n>m,\,\,\mathcal{S}(m, n)=0.\tag{$\diamond$}$$

(e.g. for $m=2$ and $n=3$ we have $0-1-4+9-16+25+36-49=0$).

How can we prove it? Is it a known result?

Comment: This is known, and it can be proved by (double) induction if one is clever with the algebra. Increasing $n$ by one leads to doubling the length of the sum, but each half of the sum acts like the other half when $n$ is larger than $m$. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet–Tarry–Escott_problem).

Comment: Oleg Kravchenko just now pointed me to a section in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem#cite_ref-2 that attributes this result to Prouhet.

Comment: If I got it right this is, indeed, an "old" trick identity. Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163369/11619) fit? (at least in my answer the indexing is offset by one, but that won't change anything really).

Comment: Seems related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1856012/19661

Comment: Nearly the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467605/19661

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! Yes, your answer to that question resolves my question completely.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm afraid I can't wrap my head around your follow up question. That's definitely more challenging :-)