# For $n\ge 6$, can we partition the set $\{1 , 4 , 9 , ...,n^2\}$ into two subsets whose sums are equal or differ by one?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, set-partition, parity

> For $n\ge 6$, can we partition the set $\{1 , 4 , 9 , ...,n^2\}$ into two subsets such that the sums of the elements in the two subsets are equal or differ by one?

For example : for $n = 10$, we can form the subsets
$S_1 = \{100 , 64 , 25 , 4\}$   and  $S2 = \{1 , 9 , 16,  36, 49, 81\}$.
$S_1$ adds up to $193$ and $S_2$ adds up to $192$.

Can we also identify the elements that we can assign to individual subsets that satisfies this property?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by two subsets having "difference $0$ or $1$". Please put the question into the main post (not just the title), and clarify all details.

Comment: I apologise for ambiguous structure of the question. I am new to this platform . I made some changes in the formulation. Please see now.

Comment: Might be useful: it's easy to see that if $n$ is "good", then $n+8$ is also "good". Just note that $(n+1)^2-(n+2)^2-(n+3)^2+(n+4)^2-(n+5)^2+(n+6)^2+(n+7)^2-(n+8)^2=0$.

Comment: @richrow: That looks very useful to me! It means that we just have to check  $n=6,7,\ldots,13$ and we are done.

Comment: This is exactly something i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @richrow Feel free to flesh that out to an answer :-) The good old $\{1,4,6,7\}$ vs. $\{2,3,5,8\}$ trick.

Comment: Wonder whether something similar holds for cubes also? Richrow's trick can be generalized to higher powers, Thue-Morse style. Well known, locally see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163369/11619).

Comment: Cubes worked for $n=10$ to $21$ before my method ran out of space, starting with $1^3+8^3+10^3$ for $n=10$

Answer (score 5):

The difference of sums is of the from $S:=\sum_{k=1}^n s_kk^2$ where each $s_k=\pm1$. Our task is to find $s_k$ such that the sum is $0$ or $1$.

Observe that $$\tag1a^2-(a+1)^2-(a+2)^2+(a+3)^2=4.$$
Therefore, we can pick four consecutive signs such that they contribute either $+4$ or $-4$.
Hence with $8$ consecutive signs, we can achieve zero contribution.
Here are the smallest non-negative sums we can achieve for some small $n$ with the eight distinct residues $\bmod 8$:
$$ \begin{align}S_0&=0&=0\\
S_1&=1^2&=1\\
S_6 &= 1^2-2^2{+3^2-4^2-5^2+6^2}&=1\\
S_7 &= 1^2+2^2-3^2{+4^2-5^2-6^2+7^2}&=0\\
S_{10}&=-1^2+2^2-3^2-4^2{+5^2-6^2-7^2+8^2}-9^2+10^2&=1\\
S_{11}&=-1^2+2^2-3^2-4^2-5^2+6^2+7^2+8^2-9^2+10^2-11^2&=0\\
S_{12}&=-1^2-2^2-3^2-4^2-5^2-6^2-7^2-8^2+9^2+10^2-11^2+12^2&=0\\
S_{13}&=-1^2-2^2-3^2-4^2-5^2-6^2-7^2+8^2+9^2-10^2+11^2+12^2-13^2&=1
\end{align}$$
We conclude that we can reach sum $=0$ or $=1$ at least when $n$ si one of $0,1,6,7,10,11,12,13$ plus a multiple of $8$. In particular, this covers all $n\ge 6$.

Comment: $S_4=16-9-4-1=2$, not $0$

Comment: I corrected it.  Works now without a hitch.

Comment: Thank you! Please help me in writing a similar expression for cubes of numbers also. I guess that holds for all n > 10 , instead of 6.

Answer (score 1):

Hagen von Eitzen's analysis can be *extended* to find subsets whose sums differ by exactly $1$, simply by noticing that $2^2 - 1^2 = 3.$

Thus, for example $1^2 + (3^2 + 6^2)$ must differ from 
$2^2 + (4^2 + 5^2)$ by exactly $1$.

Having constructed this baseline example, in a manner (again) very similar to
Hagen von Eitzen's analysis, you can (for example) construct 
$\{1,3,6,7,10,12,13\}$ and $\{2,4,5,8,9,11,14\}.$